# MAF Plugin UI content scrolling outside of bounds in main application

Tags: c#, wpf, maf

A little bit of background first, I have an application that uses the Microsoft AddIn Framework (MAF) that gets a WPF UI from the plugins (You can follow [this Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-create-an-add-in-that-returns-a-ui) to create one). This is up and working fine until the plugin content is large enough that the main form needs to scroll. When this happens, it scrolls outside of the bounds that it should.

[image: Out of bounds scrolling image]

In the image, you'll notice that the `Plugin Label Top` goes over `Main Label Top` when you scroll down some and at the bottom you'll only see `Plugin Label Bottom`. My code for the main form is the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAddinTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAddinTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="DarkGray">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Main Label Top"/>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl Name="PluginHolder"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Main Label Bottom"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`ContentControl` is what houses the plugin UI, I don't understand why the plugin UI is going over it's parent controls. I've tried housing it in different types of controls, such as a `DockPanel` and `Grid`, everything acts the same way.

Is there a special way to get this to function correctly?

If more code is needed, I'm happy to post it, https://github.com/middas/WpfAddInTest is my complete sample project that demonstrates this.

**EDIT:** Loading up the form in WPF Inspector, all I can see is an `AddInHost` control, it doesn't show any of the individual controls inside the `ContentControl`. Does this have something to do with it?
[image: WPF Inspector]

**EDIT 2:** In trying anything I can think of, I was thinking that maybe it wasn't getting the right height when it placed the control in, so I had the plugin return the desired height and set the Height of the `ContentPlaceholder` manually based on what was returned; no luck. Here is what I tried:

I updated the AddIn contracts from `GetInt()` to `GetHeight()` and on the Plugin I have this method now:

```
public double GetHeight()
{
    _Control.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

    return _Control.DesiredSize.Height;
}
```

Then on the hosting form, I have this now:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    _PluginPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Pipeline");
    _AddInPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_PluginPath, "AddIns");

    InitializeComponent();

    var warnings = new List<string>(AddInStore.Update(_PluginPath));

    _PluginToken = AddInStore.FindAddIns(typeof(IPlugin), _PluginPath, _AddInPath).FirstOrDefault();
    _Plugin = _PluginToken.Activate<IPlugin>(AddInSecurityLevel.FullTrust);

    var control = _Plugin.GetControl();
    PluginHolder.Height = _Plugin.GetHeight();

    PluginHolder.Content = control;
}
```

**EDIT 3:** Attempting to force the ZIndex doesn't seem to affect it either.

```
Panel.SetZIndex(control, -1);
```

Comment: Try setting row 1 height to "Auto" <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

Comment: Setting row 1 height to "Auto" makes it so it doesn't scroll at all and content is pushed off screen with no way to see it. If I was able to know that the content would always fit on screen, this wouldn't be an issue. I deal with multiple resolutions and an unknown plugin UI size, so scrolling is a requirement, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've finally figured out the issue. I believe the problem is because the plugin UI is outside of the AppDomain, the `ScrollViewer` doesn't know how to clip the content properly. What I finally did that worked was create a callback to the main UI that the plugin can use to be given a height that it needs to fit in. If the plugin requires scrolling, the plugin can then handle it with it's own `ScrollViewer`.

Here is the updated Contract:

```
[AddInContract]
public interface IPluginContract : IContract
{
    INativeHandleContract GetControl();

    double GetHeight();

    void SetHostCallback(IHostCallbackContract callback);
}
```

IHostCallbackContract:

```
public interface IHostCallbackContract : IContract
{
    double GetHeight();
}
```

Now before the plugin returns the `Control` it can set the Height given by the main form:

```
public FrameworkElement GetControl()
{
    if (_Callback != null)
    {
        _Control.SetHeight(_Callback.GetHeight());
    }

    return _Control;
}
```

I have updated my Git repo (https://github.com/middas/WpfAddInTest) with the entire working solution. The only issue with it now is that the scrolling isn't double buffered so it flickers. I'll have to live with that though since it doesn't appear there is a way to fix though due to WPF rendering via DirectX.

Comment: I also just found this bit of documentation confirming my findings: Add-in UIs displayed from a host application do not respect the host application's clipping behavior. (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-add-ins-overview)